# How to make a JOIN with table containing attribute value zero?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table that I defined one column to receive zero 0 as value. I did this because zero 0 represents all values. The table's name is `agendas` and the column it's `turmas_id`, this column has relationship with table `turmas` but `turmas_id` in `agendas` it's not a foreignkey because I can add 0 as saied before.

The problem is when I make a JOIN using these tables because I need return all attributes with zero value and valid keys added in table `turmas`.

I tried use LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN but the result it's not what I wait. I can use JOIN if `id` exists in table `turmas` and table `agendas` because it's a valid foreign key but I can't return other values with 0 in `agendas` attribute `turmas_id` and this is exactly what I need.

How could I do this ?

**I need display this result**

```
//table agendas
-----------------------------------------
  turmas_id   |   descricao
-----------------------------------------
    0         |   this attribute contain zero and it's not exists in table turmas
   16         |   table turmas contain id 16 it is a foreign key
    0         |   this attribute contain zero and it's not exists in table turmas
   23         |   table turmas contain id 23 it is a foreign key
```

**SQL**

```
$agendamentos = $this->Agenda->query("SELECT * FROM responsavel_alunos RespAlunos "
                . "INNER JOIN pessoas Responsavel ON (Responsavel.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id) "
                . "INNER JOIN pessoas Aluno ON (Aluno.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id1) "
                . "INNER JOIN matriculas Matricula ON (Matricula.pessoas_id = Aluno.id) "
                . "RIGHT JOIN turmas Turma ON (Turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id OR Turma.id = 0) "
                . "INNER JOIN escolas Escola ON (Escola.id = Matricula.escolas_id) "
                . "INNER JOIN agendas Agenda ON (Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id) "
                . "WHERE Responsavel.id = ? ORDER BY Agenda.created DESC "
                , array($id)); //id do responsavel
```

**Model**

[image]

**JSON result**

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "result": [
    {
      "RespAlunos": {
        "id": "5",
        "pessoas_id": "8",
        "pessoas_id1": "9",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:25:46",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:25:46"
      },
      "Responsavel": {
        "id": "8",
        "nome": "responsavel ",
        "email": "responsavel @hotmail.com",
        "tipopessoas_id": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:17:17",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:17:17"
      },
      "Aluno": {
        "id": "9",
        "nome": "aluno",
        "email": "aluno@gmail.com",
        "tipopessoas_id": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:18:41",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:18:41"
      },
      "Matricula": {
        "id": "6",
        "referencia": "238",
        "pessoas_id": "9",
        "turmas_id": "4",
        "escolas_id": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:35:08",
        "modified": "2016-02-18 10:51:20"
      },
      "Turma": {
        "id": "4",
        "descricao": "4º ano",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:31:32",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:31:32"
      },
      "Escola": {
        "id": "2",
        "descricao": "Santa Luz Unidade 2",
        "created": "2015-09-17 23:09:38",
        "modified": "2015-09-17 23:09:38"
      },
      "Agenda": {
        "id": "34",
        "data": "2016-02-29 14:40:00",
        "descricao": "<p>teste 1</p>\r\n",
        "escolas_id": "2",
        "turmas_id": "4",
        "created": "2016-02-29 14:40:21",
        "modified": "2016-02-29 14:40:21"
      }
    },
    {
      "RespAlunos": {
        "id": "5",
        "pessoas_id": "8",
        "pessoas_id1": "9",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:25:46",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:25:46"
      },
      "Responsavel": {
        "id": "8",
        "nome": "responsavel ",
        "email": "responsavel @hotmail.com",
        "tipopessoas_id": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:17:17",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:17:17"
      },
      "Aluno": {
        "id": "9",
        "nome": "aluno",
        "email": "aluno@gmail.com",
        "tipopessoas_id": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:18:41",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:18:41"
      },
      "Matricula": {
        "id": "6",
        "referencia": "238",
        "pessoas_id": "9",
        "turmas_id": "4",
        "escolas_id": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:35:08",
        "modified": "2016-02-18 10:51:20"
      },
      "Turma": {
        "id": "4",
        "descricao": "4º ano",
        "created": "2015-09-21 10:31:32",
        "modified": "2015-09-21 10:31:32"
      },
      "Escola": {
        "id": "2",
        "descricao": "Santa Luz Unidade 2",
        "created": "2015-09-17 23:09:38",
        "modified": "2015-09-17 23:09:38"
      },
      "Agenda": {
        "id": "27",
        "data": "2016-02-29 08:24:00",
        "descricao": "descricao",
        "escolas_id": "2",
        "turmas_id": "4",
        "created": "2016-02-29 08:25:20",
        "modified": "2016-02-29 08:25:20"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use IN ? instead of using = ? in your WHERE clause since your using an array variable

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `RIGHT JOIN` instead?

`"RIGHT JOIN turmas Turma ON (Turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id OR Turma.id = 0)"`

because `TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2` means all rows from `TABLE1` will be selected, even if there are no matching rows in `TABLE2`.

`RIGHT JOIN` is the opposite of it. So use `RIGHT JOIN` so that you can return your `TURMA` records based from the `ON` condition, even if there are no matching records from the preceding table.

Comment: I edited the post and added the JSON result. Look the result `Agenda` it's not contain all results with 0 in `turmas_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$agendamentos = $this->Agenda->query("SELECT * FROM responsavel_alunos RespAlunos "
                . "INNER JOIN pessoas Responsavel ON (Responsavel.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id) "
                . "INNER JOIN pessoas Aluno ON (Aluno.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id1) "
                . "INNER JOIN matriculas Matricula ON (Matricula.pessoas_id = Aluno.id) "
                . "(SELECT turmas as turma WHERE (turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id OR turma.id = 0)) AS TURMA"
                . "INNER JOIN escolas Escola ON (Escola.id = Matricula.escolas_id) "
                . "INNER JOIN agendas Agenda ON (Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id) "
                . "WHERE Responsavel.id IN ? ORDER BY Agenda.created DESC "
                , array($id)); //id do responsavel
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but throws an exception of SQL Syntax. Can you help me ?